# unity gameobject direction to player

Tags: c#

Is there a way in unity to make my newly spawned gameobject follow the player once In a straight line?
so see the picture I provided, normally the newly spawned stars will fall straight down and hit the player only if it stands under a star, now I want to make a star spawn and let it go in a straight line to the player, but I don't want the star to follow the player's movement. so only update the path of the newly spawned star once in a straight line to the player.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Et6vF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

draw a vector from star to player and add force your star when it spawned.

```cs
Vector3 dir=(player.position-star.position).normalize;
starRb.AddForce(dir*force);
```

Comment: hey, do you have discord? I cant get it to work